# Append two textures in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Given two textures that are SxT, i'd like to append them so that the result is a texture that is Sx2T, and they are vertically tiled.

In general, is it faster to create a framebuffer and render two texture-mapped quads to it, or is it faster to use something like glTexSubImage2D to update my output texture?

Comment: I would do the lazy way, download the texture data from the VRAM to your RAM, combine the textures on your CPU, and reupload them to your graphics card. That will work fine and probably won't hurt your performance too much, at least if you don't have to perform the combination every frame.

Comment: I do, my textures are frames from video cameras. There's no way that that upload cycle would be fast enough.

Comment: Are you talking about "ingame" video cameras, or actual cameras that are actually filming. In the latter case, why are the images stored as textures in your VRAM in the first place?

Comment: These are real video cameras, and they are stored as textures because the NVIDIA Tegra hardware i'm using allows that for optimization purposes; it can get video all the way through the GPU pipeline without touching CPU memory.

Comment: Does your machine support OpenGL 4? If yes, you can use `glCopyImageSubData`. I have unfortunately never used that function, but you can have a look at the [documentation by Khronos](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Storage#Texture_copy)

Comment: Well, you can use FBOs and just `glBlitFramebuffer` them, you can use FBOs and render them together, you can use FBOs and `glCopyTexSubImage` them together, you can use `glCopyImageSubData` directly on textures, and all of these paths should be reasobably fast. The most interesting question is: why do you even want to do that?